# Damerau-Levenshtein distance performance improvements

Tags: performance, c, edit-distance

I am working on a Python C-extension to calculate Damerau-Levenshtein distance. I am not really familiar with C at all--I just know that it generally has better performance. However, I am not sure how to bring about these performance gains. I translated a Python version from https://github.com/jamesturk/jellyfish/blob/main/jellyfish/_jellyfish.py basically 1:1, and the speed is fine, but I suspect I am making performance concessions an experienced C programmer would not. I would be grateful if anyone could point out anything inefficient I am doing! Also, I am just worried dealing with ASCII characters.

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include <string.h>

// This is a 1:1 translation of https://github.com/jamesturk/jellyfish/blob/main/jellyfish/_jellyfish.py

int min_int(int arr[], size_t size)
{
    // simply loop over an array of integers to find the min
    int min = arr[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        int val = arr[i];
        if (val < min)
        {
            min = val;
        }
    }
    
    return min;
}

static PyObject* distance(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    const char* s1;
    const char* s2;

    if ( !PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ss", &s1, &s2) ) // s means string argument
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    int len1 = strlen(s1);
    int len2 = strlen(s2);
    int infinite = len1 + len2;

    int nrows = len1 + 2;
    int ncols = len2 + 2;

    // initialize distance matrix
    int score[nrows][ncols];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
        {
            score[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    score[0][0] = infinite;
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= len1; i++)
    {
        score[i + 1][0] = infinite;
        score[i + 1][1] = i;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= len2; i++)
    {
        score[0][i + 1] = infinite;
        score[1][i + 1] = i;
    }
    
    // Since we are only dealing with ascii characters, this is equivalent to the dictionary
    // in the Python implementation. Instead of accessing using the character as the index, we
    // can cast the character to its integer version, and access by index.
    int da[256] = { 0 };

    for (size_t i = 1; i <= len1; i++)
    {
        int db = 0;
        for (size_t j = 1; j <= len2; j++)
        {
            const char s2_char = s2[j - 1];
            int i1 = da[(int)s2_char];
            int j1 = db;
            int cost = 1;
            if (s1[i - 1] == s2_char)
            {
                cost = 0;
                db = j;
            }
            
            int arr[4] = {
                score[i][j] + cost,
                score[i + 1][j] + 1,
                score[i][j + 1] + 1,
                score[i1][j1] + (i - i1 - 1) + 1 + (j - j1 - 1)
            };
            score[i + 1][j + 1] = min_int(arr, 4);
        }
        const char s1_char = s1[i - 1];
        da[(int)s1_char] = i;
    }
        
    long distance = score[len1 + 1][len2 + 1];

    return PyLong_FromLong(distance);
}
```

The compiler flags are `-Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk`

It's available to view and play with [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9W491cqcK). I am compiling on MacOS x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0, clang version 14.

Comment: Do you optimize the code before linking it with the python code?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand your question. This is my current, full C code. In terms of compilation, that is handled by setuptools (a Python packaging library), which to my understanding uses the same compiler flags that version of Python is compiled with. I think it uses -02?

Comment: The reason I asked is because the loops you have written are slow, but they would be fixed by the -O2 flag.

Comment: I see, I will do some more research on the compiler flags setuptools uses and edit my question. Thanks!

Comment: A https://godbolt.org link for the target you're testing would be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure the code compiles? The line `int score[nrows][ncols];` is trying to create a dynamic array on stack. I don't think it's possible.

Comment: It compiles for me! I will track down the exact compiler flags and edit the question, but it works with clang on Mac / Linux.

Comment: Ah! Got it my bad. It's the variable length arrays introduced in C99. I have rarely seen it in the wild so couldn't identify it.

Comment: Are they considered bad practice? I definitely want to work on making my C code more idiomatic as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please write this

```
int min_int(int arr[], size_t size)
{
    assert(size > 0);
```

That will avoid
[UB](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/213),
and give the caller a nice diagnostic if he messes up his
[contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract).
Or if asserts might be disabled, add an explicit `if`.

Also, it would be useful to write down why this
code doesn't target C++20 or similar which offers
[std::min](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min).
You voice concerns about speed of your code.
Using code that others wrote and tuned is one of the
best ways to address such concerns.

---

In `distance`, kudos on the very helpful `"ss"` comment, thank you.

I am sad the function isn't named
`damerau_levenshtein_distance`,
for better traceability to the python source.
Establishing traceability is important whenever
one artifact is supposed to correspond 1:1 to
another artifact.
Kudos on nicely preserving all the variable names.

The corresponding python source raises
a nicely diagnostic `TypeError` if caller messed up.
Here, maybe a NULL does something similar?
That is, we're not returning a `None` object to caller, are we?
Oh, I see, there's an exception teed up and ready to go when it
[returns false](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#c.PyArg_ParseTuple),
good.

Zeroing out the score matrix works fine.
If you benchmark you might observe
`memset` doing it quicker.
Or, ask that it be zeroed at allocation time.
(Side note: the python code uses integer objects,
implying a lot of object pointer chasing.
There's an opportunity for it to use an array instead.)

```
            int arr[4] = {
```

I understand why you create a temporary array,
going for a literal rendering of the `min` argument
in the python code. But it feels more natural here
to just compute ordinary `min()`,
more than once if necessary.
(Or `#define min4` if you feel it improves legibility.)

```
        da[(int)s1_char] = i;
```

I guess we should prefer an unsigned `ssize_t` cast, right?

And, I know you said there's an "ASCII" assumption (7 bit?),
but the `const char s1_char` declaration should probably
be unsigned. What I'm shooting for is to help
the compiler easily prove it has a valid `da` index.

The `score` entries are positive, with a signed representation,
and that seems OK.
There is an opportunity to make each entry
consume fewer bits.

The "not Unicode" assumption could be written down
more clearly.
Also, for a pair of strings
with fewer than 256 distinct codepoints,
a preprocessor could map the glyphs
to small values that work directly
with the current (unmodified) function.

---

Here's a design consideration.

I assume a python app will call this function
repeatedly in a loop.

Does it make sense to offer a *bigger* API
than what the original python source offers?
That is, would we bench quicker if an extra function let
caller pass in a **container** of words
to compute distance on?
The idea being that C iterates through
them faster than a python `for` loop would.

Comment: Performance question for everyone: Does it make a difference _where_ we allocate `score` in the C source? Like, maybe we can get improved cache line alignment? For repeated invocations, does it make sense to cache previous allocation and only grow it if current word lengths exceed the cached size? (Tiny consideration: the app logic doesn't need a zeroed allocation since it overwrites each element anyway.)

Comment: From what I can see the score is allocated on stack. That the best option performance wise. Your compiler should optimize for cache line alignment for objects stored on the stack. But I am not sure that the code even compiles. You can't have a dynamically sized array on cache

Comment: I tried searching for a min() function for C, but couldn't find one. From what I understand std::min() is from C++, is this incorrect? Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I suppose I usually see `#define min(a, b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))`, or some such foolishness. Downside with that is poor branch prediction. There are bit-twiddling [tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66850544) to compute min with no branches, so we keep the instruction pipeline full. Which is another reason to rely on code that others went to the trouble of optimizing, rather than tackling it yourself. Sometimes a compiler will choose a `CMOV` instruction FTW.

Comment: @stressed I believe the upcoming C2x has `min()`/`max()` functions.

Comment: The `assert()` avoids UB only when `NDEBUG` is undefined.  That might be sufficient, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: Granted. Yeah, I was trying to be concise, and to put it in the context of [DbC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract). I will often define a trivial `verify(c)` that blows up if boolean condition `c` is false, if there's any chance the system's asserts might be turned off in production.